# jsPerf-like app for the desktop

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there an offline desktop app that resembles jsPerf?

The nature of my work doesn't allow me to upload data to a Web site like jsPerf.

Comment: https://github.com/Lor-Saba/jsp/releases/tag/v1.0 I made this little JsPerf-like application because I needed to test and compare few codes. I'm not sure it is bug-free but should be ok for when jsperf is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Remotely resembles" is pretty vague. Do you need similar UI, or just functionality?

But functionally, [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/), which jsperf is based on can be run through node. I don't know all of what they've done to make jsperf out of Benchmark, but that might be one place to look.

It also turns out that you can [run jsperf locally](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Sorry. A similar UI and functionality is desired.

Comment: Edited my comment to note that you can apparently run jsperf locally.